# How would you say "I love you" as a goodbye?

Tags: translation, greetings

In English, if you are saying goodbye to or ending a call with a loved one, you would usually say "I love you," and the listener responds with "I love you too."

Is there an equivalent to this in Japanese? If so, what do you say to your parents, and then to your partner/spouse?

Answer (score 2):

I feel like there is no set phrase in Japanese that fits. Instead, you can say different things that show you are caring depending on the situation.

気を付けて（ね） can be said in many situations but not too versatile. It's a bit strange to say that to someone obviously not going anywhere (like someone staying in hospital).

元気でね can be said before departing or ending a phone call, but I feel like it expects an extended period of absence. I think you are less likely to say that to someone you meet or talk to everyday.

Also, you tend to explicitly mark "I'm ending this conversation" by saying something like それじゃ first.